# Launching application with parameter -hidden, trayicon crash c#

Tags: c#, parameters, tray

I found some code to get parameters in my program:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {    
        bool minimalised = false;
        if (args.Length > 0 && args[0] != null && args[0] == "-hidden")
            minimalised = true;
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Main(minimalised));
```

in Main:

```
    public Main(bool minimalised)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (minimalised)
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        else
            this.Show();
```

When I parse -hidden my program is beeing shown in tray, but when i click the icon it crashes with error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hvpjm.png

I want my aplication to stay minimalised if lauched with parameter, but be able to maxymalise it after click on trayicon.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's not enough code to tell. You're getting a stack over flow exception, so somewhere along the way you're repeatedly calling this.Show(). Put a breakpoint there, and see what is calling it so often.

Answer (score 0):

```
            this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
```

I don't know why exacly, but it helped. #FIXED